# Android – Sending/Receiving data to/from server securely

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, encryption

I am developing an Android app. The app communicates with a server through a PHP API. Each user must create an account. So, the app has a login functionality. I am doing further research on how to be able to securely transfer data between client (Android app) and server. For example, a user sends, through a POST, request his username/password in order to login.

Based on what I have read, I can safely assume that in case someone “listens” the transaction between client and server he could steal the username/password combination and use it on order to login to the legitimate user’s account. Is that correct?

The solution to this problem is to encrypt the data (eg username and password) before sending them either from client or server. The data will be then decrypted by the recipient (client or server). I do that by using crypt/decrypt functions both on client (written in Java) and server (written in PHP). Each function has the same IV (initialization vector) and Secret Key (to be honest, I do not know much about the IV’s usage so forgive me if I say something wrong. I google around for information but any useful links would be really appreciated).

From what I read, the problem with this implementation is that the APK file could be decompiled from client side and get the IV and Secret Key. As a result, a listener could decrypt the data sent. Is that correct?

Trying to find a solution to this problem I have a suggestion and I would like your opinion. What if during user’s registration a unique IV and secret key are given to the each user. These values are stored both to a MySQL database (server side) and a SQLite database (client side). Whenever data needs to be sent trough a post request, the user’s id (could be something simple as an integer) and the data to be sent are encrypted using the unique IV/Secret Key for the individual user. These are stored locally so the “listener” has no access to them. Even if he decompile the APK he will just have access to his own IV/Secret Key that he already knows. Then on server side the data are decrypted using the same IV/Secret Key stored on the server. The same procedure is applied when data are sent from server to client.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: This might help: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/how-to-securely-share-key-between-two-remote-devices

Comment: Don't you think that TLS will be much easier and better?

Comment: @Salauyou Could you please elaborate a bit more? Any useful links (examples, tutorials)?

Comment: Can you summarize your question in one sentence? Because those paragraphs are going to scare away half your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Reusing the same symmetric key and same IV is **extremely incorrect** approach and must not be used ever.

Reusing the same key and IV will enable attacks where the attacker will be able to recover your secret key just be eavesdropping on the encrypted traffic for long enough. And when the attacker has your key he will be able to decrypt all and every past and future communications.

To secure the data transfer you should use HTTPS (or SSL/TLS directly if your data transfer protocol is not HTTP-based).

Comment: +1 for the `IV` clarification, lots of people tend to reuse it or even set it to the zero array, which completely breaks the sense of the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. HTTPS seems to be complicated and I do not know if it can be implemented in a shared server.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to create a unique IV each time? How it should be communicated between client/server? What about creating a unique IV for each user as I suggested?

Comment: Definitely using some randomized seed to generate it. Opposed to the key, the `IV` value might travel publicly through the wire and might also be seen by attackers, actually only by combining the `IV` and the key messages could be decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to securely communicate with the server i suggest you to install a ssl certificate to your server. Doing this way the communication will be secured by the underlying protocol. To facilitate your communication with the server for implementing ssl communication i suggest you to use aquery library, here's [a link](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI)!. 
Also dont forget to see the ca compatibility list for android.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read about ssl but implementing an ssl certificate seems complicated to me. I also use a shared server which might be an issue.

Comment: It has happened to me that share servers also have shared ssl certificates installed already. Give it a check just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question so i'm surprised it didn't have a more complete response. It seems you understand the concepts of symmetric encryption but you are missing knowledge of public/private key encryption. Look up [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for a method of achieving public/private key encryption. With this, you can generate (via the assistance of a cryptographically secure RNG) new random keys as well as IVs at the start of each session to feed to your symmetric encryption system. This means that anyone listening from start to finish will not be able to make sense of your system short of brute forcing the RSA key or the symetric(AES?) key.